# R style Negative Indexing in Python. Take NOT IN Slices

Tags: python, r, pandas

My R programming head is wired to use negative slicing indexes to exclude elements.

As an example:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
my_neg_slice = [-2, -8, 0, -5]
```

Would return

```
[1 3 4 6 7 9]
```

i.e. return all indexes not in (0, 2, 5, 8).

This is more of a question to satisfy my curiosity as the Pythonic negative indexing is quite novel to me (this is not a critique of Python's implementation as I quite like it). Has anyone implemented a R_Style_Negative_Indexing in Python? I am very new to Python so this type of indexing may already exist? Maybe someone has created a custom extension (sorry if this is not the correct terminology) to extend an appropriate library?

Obviously, this would be very tricky to implement for strings, but I am hoping people can see the concept of wanting to slice into an object (List, Dict, DataFrame, ...) by excluding a set of known sparse elements?

My Neanderthal way to perform the negative R style indexing in Python:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
my_neg_slice = [-2, -8, 0, -5]

# Convert my_list to a numpy array as it's much easier to work with
step0 = np.array(my_list)

# Same for the negative_slices
step1 = np.array(my_neg_slice)

# Identify the indexes that are negative (assume 0 implies exclude)
step2 = step1 <= 0

# For the negative indexes, flip the sign so they are positive
step3 = -step1[step2]

# Generate the complete index for my_list
step4 = np.arange(len(my_list))

# Identify the indices required by exlucing my_neg_slice indices
step5 = np.setdiff1d(step4, step3)

# Make a cup of tea! Maybe time to rewire the brain and think like a snake!
step6 = step0[step5]

print(step6)
[1 3 4 6 7 9]
```

I dont have a particular problem that I am trying to crack, I am simply looking to build my understanding of the possibilities with indexing? Many thanks in advance.
Bertie.

Comment: A bit off-topic but I'm curious : how does R decide that 0 is a negative index ?

Comment: I am not sure if R would assume 0 was -ve, I thought in this particular case, it may make sense if requesting -ve slices in the presence of 0. It may be nice if all Python obects had list.r_style_neg_index(...), dict.r_style_neg_index(...), DataFrame.r_style_neg_index(...) - well for this trivial exercise... Thanks

Comment: @Bertie: No, R would not remove 0 when 0 is an element in a negative index.

Comment: Could that be becuase R is a 1 based array system whereas Python is o based? Thanks for the clarrification.

Comment: If you want NumPy arrays, then I would do ```my_arr = np.array(my_list)``` then ```new_arr = my_arr[np.delete(np.arange(10), np.array([2,8,0,5]))]```

Answer (score 7):

Since you've tagged this pandas, let's make `my_list` a Series:

```
In [11]: my_list = pd.Series(my_list)
```

and let's actually take the (more pythonic) "negative index" to use positives, if we don't want to do that then use a list comprehension for this part to the same effect (or if it was itself a numpy array or Series then just take `-my_neg_slice`):

```
In [12]: my_neg_slice = [2, 8, 0, 5]
```

Then, since the index of `my_list` is simply an enumeration (in this case), we can subtract:

```
In [13]: my_list.index - my_neg_slice
Out[13]: Int64Index([1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64)
```

and look at those elements in the remaining positions:

```
In [14]: my_list.iloc[my_list.index - my_neg_slice]
Out[14]: 
1    1
3    3
4    4
6    6
7    7
9    9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I cant believe how helpful everyone has been! I will take a look tomorrow! Thanks for the Pandas example. FYI, I have tried to elaborate on the question, but I have had quite a few reponses. As I do not want to repeat the points, please feel free to review some of the other replies any my comments.

Comment: @Bertie there's no "standard" way to do this, it's not really the python way to do things. One of the python things is they want there to be one way (the "right way"). If you are using pandas do the above, if numpy use a mask, otherwise use list/dict/generator comprehensions.

Answer (score 6):

Surprised no one mentioned the `drop` method in pandas:

```
In [8]: s
Out[8]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int64

In [9]: s.drop([2, 8, 0, 5])
Out[9]: 
1    1
3    3
4    4
6    6
7    7
9    9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Even though they are equal in this example, note that this use op `drop` focuses on the values in `s`, *not* on index/location. To focus on the index/location, use `a.drop([a.index[[2, 8, 0, 5]])`

Comment: @KenHBS that code has an unmatched square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Use sets:

```
>>> set([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) - set([0,2,5,8])
set([1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9])
```

(use positive values instead of negative ones).

Comment: That loses the order of the input, which is likely undesirable.

Comment: It's also based on the values in the set rather than indices (though the OP kind of confuses these issues by using a source set that consists of the same values as the indices).

Comment: Naturally, Set. How obvious. Just out of interest, how would one use this for dict? d1 = {0:'Hello', 1:'World', 2:'From', 3:'An', 4:'Autumnal', 5:'London', 'a':'Hola', 'b':'Mundo'}
my_neg_slice2 = [1, 3, 4, 'b']
keys = set(d1) - set([1, 3, 4, 'b'])
When entering d1[keys], this does not work? Thanks

Comment: d2 = dict([(k,v) for k,v in d1.items() if k in keys])

Comment: Yes Brent, that works... Although I think if this was considered useful and a person frequently encoutners this particular problem they need to address, it may be more elegant to extend various libraries so that there is a .r_style_neg_index(...) so that you can call the method on list, dict, DataFrame, ...  Thanks.

Comment: If R-style notation is your goal, then create a new `class Rdict(dict):` with a method `def neg_slice(self, slice):` to perform the slice on a given list.  Rdict will inherit the dictionary class.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a slightly different format for `my_neg_slice`, but the following is a Pythonic way to filter an iterable in the way you are describing:

```
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> my_neg_slice = set([2, 8, 0, 5])
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if i not in my_neg_slice]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: I guess your way would work well for dict's and DataFrames? Is it easy to custom modify the standard libraries to add a .r_style_neg_index method? Thanks. p.s. I have added comments to other replies I have had that elaborates...

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question ! I thought I'd try to provide a `numpy` version. As far as I know it would have to rely on a process similar to the one you gave, where you'd build up a list of the indices in the data and then eliminate the ones you don't want.

```
mask = np.ones(len(my_list), dtype=bool)
for i in my_neg_slice:
    mask[i] = False
my_list[mask]
```

It's a little wasteful, though, in the sense that your mask array would need to have as many elements in it as `my_list`. The answer by @F.J is nice because it retains the sparsity of the "not in" slice.

#### Update

Just found a `numpy` mailing list post that seems to confirm you'd need to do this using some sort of masking : http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-May/034021.html

Comment: Thanks. I would like to point out that my quesiton was more of a generic question that equally aplies to dict, DataFrame and other Python objects... The kind responses from everyone seems to confirm there is no standard .r_style_neg_index method(...) for the objects? Maybe it will appear in Python (-3.5) in a parallel universe :)

Comment: That's correct, as far as I've seen in Python the idea of indexing using a set complement or "negative" isn't common. I'll keep my eye out for Python -3.5 though !

Comment: I prefer this approach too. And since `mask` is a `numpy.array`, one can replace the `for` statement, by just: `mask[my_neg_slice] = False`.